# s3 bucket tri-directional replication using pulumi

Tags: amazon-s3, replication, pulumi

I faced a problem that I need to mutually replicate S3 buckets in three regions us-west-2, us-east-1, and eu-west-2. I saw in the Pulumi doc, it has [a bi-directional replication example](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/s3/bucketreplicationconfig/#bi-directional-replication). I am wondering whether I need to create 6 replication rules like

```
US West 2 -> US East 1
US East 1 -> US West 2
US West 2 -> EU West 2
EU West 2 -> US West 2
US East 1 -> EU West 2
EU West 2 -> US East 1
```

Appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't been able to find the information I'm about to share in the docs or articles.

From my experience, S3 replication is not transitive.

If you have set up these replications:

- A < - > B
- A < - > C

Adding an object to C will replicate it to A but will not replicate it to B.

For that to happen, you need to also set up bi directional replication between B and C.

Your final replication strategy should be:

- A < - > B
- A < - > C
- B < - > C